# Page unpublished and deleted from CME, but page entry still exists in DB. How to clean the entry in DB?

Tags: publishing, cme, broker

I unpublished a Page from CME and after successful unpublish from publishing queue, deleted the page. But when I checked the DB, I still see the entry of the page. 
Now there is no way for me to try publishing and unpublishing the page as the page is deleted.

How can the entry from DB tables be removed?

Answer (score 16):

Actually there is a better and far safer solution than the one @Nuno proposes. What you can do is "mock unpublish process". You can capture undeploy transport package on CD side of some other page, then change it to have id of your page (change XML that contains inpublish instructions), and copy it into incoming folder of deployer. Deployer will pick it up and process just like it came from CM. This is actually something that SDL customer support proposed to us some time ago, so we have implemented it on our side.

I have already answered to similar question [here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/15942/1678)

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer just in case someone thought it was a good idea :)

Comment: Nice! I've always gone with drop recreate republish which is a nightmare!

Comment: Steps to create a fake undeploy package in KB article https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000001598