# How can I have two different PAGE_ID values for the same URL in LINK_INFO

Tags: broker

In the LINK_INFO of my broker database, I can see that for a given URL there are several records. I'd expect that these should all have the same PAGE_ID but this is not so. (I'm looking at records for a specific publication)

When I try to find the matching page in the Content Manager, only one of the page IDs matches. As far as I can tell this means the broker data is corrupt. Is there any other reasonable explanation?

Assuming it is a question of corrupt data, is there a way to get rid of the problematic records other than decommission/delete/republish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, broker database can contain few pages with same URL. Please check my answer to similar question [here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18998/multiple-page-id-in-broker-db/18999#18999) Same URL is not result of corrupt broker, but issues with CM-CD where unique name/url constraint only exist on CM, but you don't have to republish every time you change it. Also, existing pages in broker but not in CM are possible. Please check last years Tridion Developer Summit presentation by [@Atila Sos](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/1169/atila-sos). Idea to delete these orphan items is to create undeploy packages with orphan items, place them in deployer and it will pick them up and do undeploy from broker. This is something SDL customer support provided as a solution to us.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a corrupt CD Content Store to me, indeed.

Do you have records for those Page IDs in your PAGES table?

I shall not mention a SQL DELETE statement as an (unsupported) option; this can be very tricky given the implicit references between tables.

So, indeed, starting with a clean CD Content Store and republishing is the recommended/supported way to fix such corruption.