# Tridion CMS and Broker database out of sync

Tags: sdl-tridion, content-manager, broker, sites-9

I am displaying tridion component (with TCM ID) on the web page, but when I search the same id in tridion cms, it is not there, but we do have the component in broker database seems. Can it be possible that if we unpublish and delete an item from CMS, but didn't get deleted from broker database? Please suggest. I would like to delete that item from displaying on the webpage. I am using Tridion Site 9.

Comment: Which item type Is that page or component or binary? I would advise to reach out SDL support to handle this properly. DO NOT CHANGE anything yourself.

Comment: If it's binary then this article might help - https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004608

Comment: Probably related to https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/how-can-i-have-two-different-page-id-values-for-the-same-url-in-link-info. Back in 2017 Atila Sos presented a tool that fixes inconsistencies between the cm and broker but I don't know if it's available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to look like your case orphan records in content broker database, or could be a chance those binaries to be used in other pages not sure.

If the item does not exist in the CM, then you cannot send the publish transaction from the CM.

If the binaries are orphaned as in, they were published together with a page, but somehow the page got unpublished, but the binary is still there: Then it is a data consistency issue, definitely a support case, please raise to SDL support to involve they can help you with the right SQL query to remove the records, I would not recommend to do anything by your self to resolve this issue.

**Any tampering over databases without instructions from SDL customer support is UNSUPPORTED.**

Comment: The issue is with the component (not binary or page)

Comment: then it's possible to prepare the unpublish package based on existing similar DCP component to unpublish and prepare the unpublish action and based on the earlier shared in the comment gateway knowledge articke we should be able to remove that DCP component. The deployer due to statestore database it works little bit different compare to 2013SP2 deployers, so please reach out SDL customer support to resolve this issue