# Publishing content does not update the site

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, dd4t

We have two publishing targets, staging and live.

When we publish certain pages, the content is not updated on the staging site, even though the publishing job shows a 'Success' message in the queue. Publishing the same page to live works just fine, with the content updated.

Other pages can also be published to staging and the content updates accordingly. Is there any reason why content for certain pages would not update, when publishing to a specific target, with a 'Success' message being displayed? Is there some other suggested ways to diagnose the problem? We've looked in server logs.

We’ve tried:

- To restart the HTTP deployer and all Tridion windows services
- To build the page with the Tridion template builder (this works as expected, with expected output produced).
- We’ve seen a few errors from the last few days in the logs: ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: http://servername:8082/httpupload.aspx reason: Internal Server Error. This could be related, but is not logging any error for the specific publish transaction, so it may be a red herring.
- To increase the length of the URL – we’ve had issues where the URL has been too long in the past (as the deployer task which adds the xml files on to the server fails because the total length of the path on the file system exceeds the maximum allowable characters). However, I don’t think this is the problem here as when we increase the length of the URL, publishing to staging still works.
- I also don't think it's link levels that is the problem, as it wouldn't work to publish the page to another target then. Also, if items were checked out or in a workflow, then we also wouldn't see the latest content when publishing to the live target.

UPDATE: I've checked the Tridion Broker database and the [PAGE_CONTENT] table has got the latest text in the 'Content' column for the given page id. Hence, I'm thinking that the reason why the content is not updating on our staging site must be because of some caching issue. The cd_storage_conf.xml file has `ObjectCache Enabled="false"` set in it. Is there any other caching that could be happening, which means that old content is served?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the page contents gets published in the broker database, , so not on the filesystem. Does this mean you are using DXA, or DD4T, or any other custom built framework ?

Comment: Yes, we use DD4T

Comment: Can you check that the cd_storage_conf.xml of the deployer contains the same database information as the cd_storage_conf.xml of the content service (or the web application in case of an in-process setup)?

Comment: I've checked this, and the only difference is that the pool size is different. It's 5 in one and 10 in the other, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: And I guess if you restart the web application on staging, the new content is showing?

Comment: If the updated content is available in the broker, we can pretty much rule out the publishing and deployment prophecies in SDL. If you restart your web application, does the latest content come up? I suggest that you read Albert's blog (https://albertromkes.com/2012/04/07/dd4t-and-caching/)? Also, can you update the question with your application cache configurations for Staging website?

Comment: Even if I restart the web application, the old content is still showing. As for the caching: 1) The OutputCache folder on the web server is empty, 2) The DD4T caching has the following setting in the web.config: key="DD4T.CacheSettings.Default" value="-1", 3) The ObjectCache has got attribute Enabled="false" in the cd_storage_conf. Hence, I don't think there should be any caching enabled for the site.

Comment: Based on the version of DD4T, the call back interval value may not be needed. In any case, can you add a key for CallBack and also explicitly set page and component cache for a very low value like 5 secs?<add key="CacheSettings_CallBackInterval" value="30"/>
<add key="DD4T.CacheSettings.Page" value="5"/>
<add key="DD4T.CacheSettings.Component" value="5"/>

Comment: just a quick question: are the certain pages in the same publication as the pages that show up? Is there any difference no matter how small between the showing and non-showing pages?

Comment: @Shiva I've got all of those settings set to really low values already.

Comment: I've got a bit further with this. In the [Tridion_Broker].[dbo].[PAGE] table on the database, I've found that we have two records with the same filename and URL. When I look at the content of those two records in the PAGE_CONTENT table, one record has got the new content, and the other record has got the old content. However, the old content is displayed on the site. Is there any way to get rid of the record in these tables displaying the old content? I don't want to be running delete statements against the database, as I don't know what other dependencies there might be on these page ids.

Comment: Note also that I can't find the TCM id in the CMS of the first page record in the broker database. What I'm guessing has happened is that the original page (with the old content) has been deleted from the CMS, but has somehow not become unpublished in the broker database first. Is that possible at all?

Comment: This looks like a similar issue to the one we've been experiencing, so i'll try that: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/clean-the-ghost-published-records/15942#15942

Comment: You can try it out and update your question. It looks like the findings are different from your original question. It looks to an issue with legacy code or COM APIs or maybe an incorrect implementation of any dd4t cm side customization, if any. You need to get to the root cause of it as well. Suggest that you leave your deployer running in DEBUG mode to isolate the issue with CM vs. CD. Hopefully, you get to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the problem was similar to that for a question already published here:

[Clean the ghost published records](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/clean-the-ghost-published-records/15942#15942)

For some reason we had a bunch of 'orphan records', which were pulled in for the given page URL when publishedm, instead of the content for the new page TCM id.

Doing what was suggested by Marko at the above link allowed us to work around the problem.